# Special Character "- " in the Elastic Search acting

Tags: elasticsearch

"-" is acting like a or operator for e.g. I am searching "t-link", then it showing the result containing "t-link" as well as "t", why it is giving two terms, but i interested  in the "t-link", why it is happening so? How can i recover from it?

Answer (score 8):

Elasticsearch is using by default the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for strings.

Basically, your string is tokenized in two tokens, lowercased:

- t
- link

If you need to know what does elasticsearch with your fields, use the [_analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d 't-link'
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=simple' -d 't-link'
```

If you don't want that, make sure you [put the right mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for that field and use either a [simple analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) or a [keyword analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) or no analyzer at all depending on your requirements. See also [String core type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string).

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "simple"},
            "other" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

Using this form `message` field will be analyzed with `simple` analyzer and `other` field won't be analyzed at all.

Comment: what are the two tokens it has formed? Please specify them?

Comment: Please provide the link where I can find the example of analyzer?